# How to refactor / re-architect the components/state here in ui-router app

Tags: javascript, angular.js, user-interface, state-machine

https://plnkr.co/edit/bOZW1a9u62W1QA6cYjYj?p=preview

My goal has been to separate the `Dashboard` states from the `Feed` state.
Inside the Dashboard state these are the following views: Tickers, Tags, Social.

Changes in those 3 should not effect the Feed module. (However changes from the Feed will eventually need to update the other 3)

I finally achieved this by adding the `<feed-module></feed-module>` to the root of the index file. Right underneath the first `<div ui-view></div>`.

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view></div>
  <feed-module></feed-module>
</div>
```

This is of course not ideal, because **(1):** There should only be 1 ui-view on the index, and **(2):** This exposes the feedModule outside of the login state.

I have an idea of perhaps going from the `login` state to a `container` state that will hold the dash-module and feed-module together, but have gotten no success yet. [You can see an attempt here](https://plnkr.co/edit/t33jOoFKUBNQ4Iifs0cq?p=preview).

[image]

Full code to top Plnkr link here:

```
// Feed module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var feed = angular.module('feed', ['ui.router'])

feed.config(function($stateProvider) {

  const feed = {
    name: 'feed',
    url: '/feed',
    templateUrl: '<em>Feed items go here.</em>'
  }

  $stateProvider.state(feed);

})

feed.component('feedModule', {
  templateUrl: 'feed-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Feed init (only once)', $state.params);
  }
})

// RouterApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'feed']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    const login = {
      name: 'login',
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'l',
      controller: function($state) {
        this.login = function() {
          $state.go('dashboard', {});
        }
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
      name: 'dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      params: {
        ticker: {},
        tags: {}
      },
      views: {
        '' : {
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        },
        'tickers@dashboard': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-module-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('Tickers init', $state.params);

            $scope.tickers = [
              { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
              { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
              { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
            ];

            $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
              console.log(' ')
              console.log('Ticker clicked!')
              $state.go('dashboard', { ticker: ticker });
            }
          }
        },
        'tags@dashboard' : {
          templateUrl: 'tags-module-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];

            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }

            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];

            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }

            console.log('Tags init', $state.params);
            // console.log(' Tags model', tags_model);
          }
        },
        'social@dashboard' : {
          templateUrl: 'social-module-template.html', 
          controller: function($state) {
            console.log('Social init', $state.params);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(login)
      .state(dashboard);
});
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a new module called `container` which you are redirected to from the `login` state.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ivpBrncRKAXxhoYlm6uY?p=preview

```
// Container module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var container = angular.module('container', [ 'ui.router' ])
    container.config(function($stateProvider) {
      const container = {
        name: 'container',
        url: '/container',
        templateUrl: 'app.container.html'
      }

      $stateProvider.state(container);
    });
```

And the app.container.html looks like so:

```
<div>
  <dashboard-module></dashboard-module>
  <feed-module></feed-module>
</div>
```

I'm still having problems with sibling and parent -> child $state communication, but those are different questions.